# How does one use oauth in a FLOSS app where we can't keep a secret key?

Tags: open-source, twitter, oauth

How does one use oauth in a FLOSS app where we can't keep a secret key? If other see the secret and the key, can't he use it to use the user account as if he where me?

Comment: What do you mean, "can't keep a secret key"? "there is no trustworthy place to store it"? Which "other" are you talking about?

Comment: @piskvor: if it's open source, how can it hide the secret key? You can just retrieve it the same way the app does. "other" means an unauthorized third party. 

Someone could take the app key and use it to impersonate the app and get the user's data?

Comment: "Open source" is a way of licensing, meaning approximately "if you are further __distributing__ the program, you must pass the source code to the recipients" not "if you are __using__ the program, you must allow anyone to see your source code, as it is on your servers". You don't have to give/show the source to anyone, as long as you're not distributing it.

Comment: @Piskvor Open Source means the source code can be seen by anyone. We're talking about writting an Open Source app here.

Comment: This is a desktop application, the code is running in the user's computer, not on a server.

Comment: @Juanjo Conti: That is a common misconception. Open Source means that __if you decide to publish your changes to the code__ (i.e. distribute the code), the source code can be seen by the public. If you decide to __not distribute__ your changes, you can sit on them and never release them. See e.g. this FAQ for GPL, the most common Open Source license: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic

Comment: @Roberto Alsina: Aha. In that case, I think you are indeed distributing the code. Why do you need to keep the secret key there? That's its purpose, to verify that it's *you*, trying to authorize. If the purpose inn your app is  "so that the user can authorize to Twitter", shouldn't the user input *their* secret key somewhere in the configuration?

Comment: @piskvor we are writing the app, of course we are distributing it too, or else how would anyone use it? :-)


We are talking about the secret per-app key most OAuth sites give you. In this particular case it's goodreads.com, but it could just as well be flickr.com, for example.


Twitter has a different scheme with a PIN, so it's not relevant here.


The user has to have the app's secret key to get the "do you allow whateverapp to access your data?" page in the site.

Answer (score 5):

I have dealt with the issue in my own open source Twitter apps.

You do NOT distribute the ConsumerKey or ConsumerKeySecret with your source code.  A reasonable approach is to create two constants/global variables (or whatever) that hold these values, and these are EMPTY in the source that you publish.  Include some documentation that explains to other developers how to acquire their own keys and how to modify the source to install them.

If you are distributing compiled binaries, you would compile with the ConsumerKey and ConsumerKeySecret values populated so the application runs.

There is no -perfectly secure- way to handle this; it's the nature of OAuth.  You can, however, be -reasonably- secure, and that's what this approach achieves.